# Setting a default object property, and ensuring you have only a single default property

Tags: c#

This is our model.

```
public class Issue {
     public virtual string Summary {get;set;}
     public virtual string Description {get;set;}
     public virtual Priority Priority {get;set;}
     ...
}

public class Priority {
     public virtual string Name {get;set;}
     public virtual string Description {get;set;}
     public virtual bool IsDefault {get;set;}
}
```

Any recommendations on a good way to go about ensuring that only one "Priority" IsDefault? We need the default priority to be changeable in the UI.

Comment: I'm not following.  An `Issue` can have only one `Priority`.  Where is there more than one `Priority` and what does _"only one "Priority" IsDefault"_ mean in the context of your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

```
  public class Issue
    {
        public virtual string Summary { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }

        public Issue()
        {
            Priority = new Priority();
        }

    }
```

The other way would be:

```
public class Issue
{
    public virtual string Summary { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public Priority Priority = new Priority();
}
```

Notice that the `virtual` needs to be removed. Unless you are doing something OOP heavy or using Entity Framework, the use of `virtual` or `new`is a liability.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you are trying to do:

```
public class Priority {
     public virtual string Name {get;set;}
     public virtual string Description {get;set;}
     public virtual bool IsDefault {get;set;}
}



  public class Priorities
    {
        public List<Priority> PriorityList;
        public Priorities()
        {
              PriorityList = new List<Priority>();
    
        }
        public void setDefault(int index)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<PriorityList.Count;i++)
            {
                 if(i != index)
                 {
                    PriorityList[i].IsDefault = false;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     PriorityList[i].IsDefault = true;
                 }
            }
         }
        }
    
    }
```

You don't really have to encapsulate your list in a class like that if you don't want but it does make it easier to set a default.   If you have a list of priorities saved elsewhere you can always make setDefault a static function.  if you did it this way, Priorities should probably be made enumerable and obviously have the ability to add and remove.

If you are trying to save a global default, remove the IsDefault

```
public class Priority {
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string Description {get;set;}
     public Priority CopyPriority()
     {
         return (Priority)this.MemberwiseClone();
     }
}
```

elsewhere have a single priority object serialized somewhere.

```
void setDefault(Priority newDefault)
{
    savedDefault = newDefault.CopyPriority();
}
```